# Not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot figure out why I am getting a not valid month error. I can return each field with using a to_date without error but when I add the between filter it bombs out. I am using Oracle. The weird thing is not every record bombs out

```
SELECT *
  FROM timedetail_dates
 WHERE empnum = '501331134'
   AND (TO_DATE ('10/14/2016 04:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
           BETWEEN TO_DATE (timein_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
               AND TO_DATE (timeout_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
       )
   AND tsdate BETWEEN '09-oct-2016' AND '22-oct-2016'
   AND timedetail_dates.DURATION > 0;
```

Comment: Which dbms? (TO_DATE is a product specific function.)

Comment: Can you add the tag for Oracle

Comment: What is the datatype of your `timein_date`, `timeout_date` and `tsdate` columns? My guess is that `tsdate` is of DATE or TIMESTAMP datatype, and you need to add to_date's around the `'09-oct-2016'` and `'22-oct-2016'` strings.

Comment: Data type of those 2 fields is varchar. tsdate is a date field. The timeout_date time is midnight in the example that doesn't work. Other records return without error if I use a different date

Comment: Why are you storing DATEs in a VARCHAR column?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your dates in your BETWEEN clause in TO_DATE as well like

```
AND tsdate BETWEEN TO_DATE('09-oct-2016', 'dd-MON-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('22-oct-2016', 'dd-MON-yyyy')
```

Also, if your tsdate column is not a date type, you'll need to wrap it, too, within the format of how you're storing the data in the column.

Comment: Its definitly happening on the between portion. The timein_date and timeout_date are coming from a view in a varchar field.

Comment: OK - did you try using to_date in your BETWEEN statement?

Comment: No but even when I comment out the tsdate between part it still errors

Comment: So is the behavior different now?  In your OP you said it only errs when the BETWEEN logic is added.

Comment: AND (TO_DATE ('10/14/2016 04:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
           BETWEEN TO_DATE (timein_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
               AND TO_DATE (timeout_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
       )

Comment: Sorry if I'm being a little dense, but if you comment out the 2nd BETWEEN, does the query work?

Comment: @user1143409 also, out of curiosity, is the format of the timein_date and time_out_date columns really `mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi`? Sounds like maybe it isn't - you should ideally check the statement that creates the view to determine the actual format (assuming that the dates were converted to strings in the view, that is). If the dates are actually being stored as strings in the database, then it sounds like maybe you have rows where the strings are in different formats (e.g. some have 'dd/mm/yyyy' some have 'mm/dd/yyyy', some have 'mon/dd/yyyy; etc)

Answer (score 0):

#### Cause of the error:

It sounds like you have an invalid date in your table. You receive this error when the string being parsed is incorrect. Here's an example query that produces it.

```
SELECT TO_DATE('22-10-2016 05:31', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') FROM DUAL;
```

#### Prevent this from happening again:

As [a_horse_with_no_name implies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158344/not-a-valid-month#comment67590292_40158344), using `VARCHAR` (or `VARCHAR2` or any text type) is usually a poor data type for temporal data. This is part of the reason why: it's difficult to prevent invalid data from getting into the database.

You need to prevent bad data from getting into the database to start with:

1. The ideal solution is to convert these columns to an actual temporal type (after you repair the existing data), such as `TIMESTAMP` (possibly `WITH TIME ZONE`) or `DATE`.
2. If that isn't possible, then add a constraint or trigger that will throw an error on the wrong format. Note that you need to figure out what the "right" format is. Part of the problem here might be that you have non-American users (or maybe computer savvy people who like ISO 8601), and applications will need to either enforce a particular format or automatically parse to the standard you decide on
3. If you *really* can't prevent different formats from coming in *and* can't convert to an actual date, then you could store an extra column with the format. You would still need to validate that the date actually matches whatever format is contained in the same row.
4. You should also look at any applications that are adding data to this database. They likely lack validation of the input or contain bugs that allow invalid data to be created.

#### Fix the existing data:

To find the offending row, try this. First create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATETIME_IS_VALID_FOR_FORMAT(
  TEXT_DATETIME VARCHAR2,
  DATETIME_FORMAT VARCHAR2
)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    DUMMYVAR DATE;
  BEGIN
    -- The assignment is only here to get the function to compile
    DUMMYVAR := TO_DATE(TEXT_DATETIME, DATETIME_FORMAT);
    RETURN 'TRUE';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN 'FALSE';
  END;
/
```

Now `SELECT` the rows where this is `'FALSE'`:

```
SELECT *
FROM timedetail_dates
WHERE
  DATETIME_IS_VALID_FOR_FORMAT(timein_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') != 'TRUE' OR
  DATETIME_IS_VALID_FOR_FORMAT(timeout_date, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') != 'TRUE'
```

If you can't create functions because of low privileges on the database, you'll have to leverage `DBMS_OUTPUT` instead. Replace `ID_COLUMN` in the anonymous block below, and you can use it to find the bad rows:

```
DECLARE
  FUNCTION DATETIME_IS_VALID_FOR_FORMAT(
    TEXT_DATETIME VARCHAR2,
    DATETIME_FORMAT VARCHAR2
  )
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
      DUMMYVAR DATE;
    BEGIN
      -- The assignment is only here to get the function to compile
      DUMMYVAR := TO_DATE(TEXT_DATETIME, DATETIME_FORMAT);
      RETURN 'TRUE';
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN 'FALSE';
    END;
BEGIN
  FOR T_ROW IN (SELECT * FROM timedetail_dates) LOOP
    IF (
      DATETIME_IS_VALID_FOR_FORMAT(T_ROW.TIMEIN_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') != 'TRUE' OR
      DATETIME_IS_VALID_FOR_FORMAT(T_ROW.TIMEOUT_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi') != 'TRUE'
    ) THEN
      -- Replace ID_COLUMN with your actual primary key
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Bad row: '||T_ROW.ID_COLUMN);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Note that you'll probably have to do some preparation to make your client start capturing the output from `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. (This is client dependent, but you have to turn it on in both SQL*Plus and Oracle SQL Developer.) Also note that none of the output will show up until the block *completes*.